# Uploading package to App Store Connect using Fastlane is uploading it also on the TestFlight builds list

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect, fastlane

When I upload my application to AppStore Connect using upload_to_app_store(), it is also uploading a version to TestFlight, and this causes the default version in TestFlight to be the last one uploaded to the AppStore.

So, in my workflow, when I push my app to my 'sandbox' branch, I only upload to TestFlight using upload_to_testflight(), we are good here. After that, I push the latest changes from 'sandbox' to my 'production' branch. When I do this last step, in addition to uploading to the AppStore, it is also uploading the build to TestFlight, causing the version in TestFlight to be connected to the production server. I don't know why is happening that.

Here is the lane executed when pushing to sandbox:

```
desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :deploy_testflight do
    set_full_version()

    setup_ci if is_ci

    cocoapods(clean_install: is_ci)

    match(
      type: "appstore",
      readonly: is_ci,
    )

    build_app(
      workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "Runner",
      archive_path: "../build/ios/Runner.xcarchive",
      output_directory: "../build/ios/Runner",
    )

    upload_to_testflight(
      api_key_path: "./app_store_connect.json",
      ipa: '../build/ios/Runner/Runner.ipa',
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
    )
  end
```

And this when pushing to production:

```
desc "Push a new release build to App Store"
  lane :deploy_appstore do
    set_full_version()

    setup_ci if is_ci

    cocoapods(clean_install: is_ci)

    match(
      type: "appstore",
      readonly: is_ci,
    )

    build_app(
      workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "Runner",
      archive_path: "../build/ios/Runner.xcarchive",
      output_directory: "../build/ios/Runner",
    )

    upload_to_app_store(
      force: true,
      reject_if_possible: true,
      skip_metadata: false,
      skip_screenshots: true,
      languages: ['en-US'],
      release_notes: {
        "default" => "Updates",
        "en-US" => "Updates",
      },
      submit_for_review: true,
      automatic_release: true,
      precheck_include_in_app_purchases: false,
      submission_information: {
        add_id_info_limits_tracking: true,
        add_id_info_serves_ads: false,
        add_id_info_tracks_action: true,
        add_id_info_tracks_install: true,
        add_id_info_uses_idfa: true,
        content_rights_has_rights: true,
        content_rights_contains_third_party_content: true,
        export_compliance_platform: 'ios',
        export_compliance_compliance_required: false,
        export_compliance_encryption_updated: false,
        export_compliance_app_type: '',
        export_compliance_uses_encryption: false,
        export_compliance_is_exempt: false,
        export_compliance_contains_third_party_cryptography: false,
        export_compliance_contains_proprietary_cryptography: false,
        export_compliance_available_on_french_store: false
      },
      api_key_path: "./app_store_connect.json",
      ipa: '../build/ios/Runner/Runner.ipa',
    )
  end
```

Comment: This is just how App Store Connect works. When you upload a build, it goes to TestFlight and becomes available for submission to the App Store

Comment: So there is no way to achieve what I want ? After uploading to AppStore I will need to upload again to sandbox to have a testing version of my app ?

Comment: And also I'm not uploading to TestFlight in my second lane, I'm uploading directly to the AppStore but it is going to TestFlight too... And this is when I have the problem because the last TestFlight build is connected to the production api

Comment: TestFlight builds are full production builds. The idea is that once a specific build goes through testing, it can be released to the App Store without recompiling. Apps that require a backend server should typically point their TestFlight builds to their production backend environment. If you want to do something different from that, you'd need to manage it yourself

Comment: With that said, the latest beta version of Xcode includes a feature to upload to TestFlight and not the App Store, though I'm not sure if it's available in Fastlane yet or not. Production builds would then go to TestFlight, as well, so if you don't want testers to access those, you'd need to set up appropriate tester groups and send specific test builds to those groups yourself

Comment: Yeah okay I have a clear idea now. So when uploading to App Store the build uploaded is also going to be available in TestFlight. I'm right ? Comment: (Yes only uploading to TestFlight is already available in Fastlane)

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Answer (score 0):

That's unrelated to *fastlane*, actually. It's just how the App Store Connect works.

The idea is that after the app has been tested via TestFlight, you'd release that same binary, and not upload a new one (via a different branch, or any other reason).

If you feel strongly about keeping your current process, the closest pseudo-solution you'd get is to upload 2 different apps (with different bundle identifiers), e.g. `com.example.staging` from your sandbox branch, and `com.example` from your production branch.

However, I'd recommend changing your processes instead of working around the system. Adapt them according to how the ecosystem works (in this case, App Store Connect), and you'll have less trouble :)